# Why is crond failing to run a non-root crontab on alpine linux?

Tags: cron, docker, alpine-linux

I am having a nasty time running a non-root crontab file on Alpine Linux.

I've been through two other cron related posts and I don't have an answer:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working

https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Here is the setup.

My crontab looks like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash

* * * * * /opt/monitor/monitor.sh >> /var/log/monitor.log 2>&1
0 3 * * * /opt/monitor/monitor-log-clean.sh >> /var/log/monitor.log 2>&1
```

My Dockerfile is a little messy now, but only because I have been desperately trying to resolve this. It looks something like this. In short, I add SUID for crontab -e to work as other users, I create my user, I import my crontab file, and then I provide permissions to everything I can think of.

```
FROM alpine:3.5

# DEPENDENCY TO ALLOW USERS TO RUN crontab -e
RUN apk add --update busybox-suid

# I LIKE BASH
RUN apk --no-cache add bash bash-doc
RUN apk --no-cache add util-linux pciutils usbutils coreutils binutils findutils grep

#... lots of custom stuff ...    

# CREATE USER
RUN adduser -S robuser && \
    mkdir -p /home/robuser

# ADD ENTRY POINT
ADD src/entrypoint.sh /home/robuser/entrypoint.sh

# GIVE MY USER ACCESS
RUN mkdir /etc/cron.d
RUN echo "robuser" > /etc/cron.allow
RUN echo "" >> /etc/cron.allow
RUN chmod -R 644 /etc/cron.d

# ADD MY CRONTAB
RUN mkdir -p /var/spool/cron/crontabs
ADD ./src/crontab.conf /tmp/cloudwatch/crontab.conf
RUN crontab -u robuser /tmp/cloudwatch/crontab.conf

# DEBUG... GIVE MY USER ACCESS TO EVERYTHING
RUN chown -R robuser /etc/cron.d
RUN chmod -R 755 /etc/cron.d
RUN chown -R robuser /var/spool/cron
RUN chmod -R 744 /var/spool/cron
RUN chown robuser /var/spool/cron/crontabs
RUN chmod 744 /var/spool/cron/crontabs
RUN chown -R robuser /etc/crontabs
RUN chmod -R 744 /etc/crontabs
RUN chown robuser /etc/crontabs/robuser
RUN chmod -R 744 /etc/crontabs/robuser
RUN chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/robuser

# ADD MY MONITORING PROGRAM
RUN mkdir -p /opt/monitor
ADD src/monitor /opt/monitor
RUN mkdir -p /opt/monitor/.tmp && \
    chown -R robuser /opt/monitor && \
    chmod -R 700 /opt/monitor

RUN touch /var/log/entrypoint.log && \
    touch /var/log/monitor.log && \
    touch /var/log/cron.log && \
    touch /var/log/awslogs.log && \
    chown -R robuser /var/log

USER robuser

ENTRYPOINT /home/robuser/entrypoint.sh
```

meanwhile, my entrypoint.sh has this somewhere in it. I start the cron daemon as a background service and log to cron.log verbosely. I've also tried specifying -d 0 to get even more debug, but the didn't really add anything to the output.

```
#!/bin/bash

crond -b -l 0 -L /var/log/cron.log

#... lots of other startup stuff ...
```

An important point: If I don't switch to *robuser*, **everything works okay as root**.

If I check the *cron.log*, its pretty empty:

```
crond: crond (busybox 1.25.1) started, log level 0
crond: wakeup dt=45
crond: wakeup dt=60
crond: wakeup dt=60
```

Meanwhile, /var/log/monitor.log is completely empty (see crontab at the beginning of the post).

So crond is not printing any errors.

I've tried everything i can think of to debug this. There's no error message. It simply runs and never prints. A good suggestion was to simplify my crontab, but this also did not work:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash

* * * * * touch /tmp/test.txt
```

I've tried searching for other alpine containers who use non-root cron, but most people don't go through the trouble of getting their Alpine containers to run non-root.

Does anyone have any further suggestions to help debug this?

Comment: Giving your user "access to everything" may break things when security checks fail on files that must not be owned by random users.

Comment: "A good suggestion was to simply my crontab". Did you mean to write "simplify"?

Comment: Possibly dumb question, but where are the results of the crontab supposed to be mailed to? You don't have a MAILTO? And do you have mail enabled? If so, have you checked the mail spool? And maybe start with testing something simple like a print command.

Comment: Oh, I see. "I start the cron daemon as a background service and log to cron.log verbosely." Maybe try doing it a different way? The usual reporting is via mail, isn't it?

Comment: @Faheem
1) Yes, I meant simplify
2) This is a lightweight version of cron specifically for Alpine Linux. The point is to remove lots features to make the O.S. as small as possible, but still keep the core. So things like syslog aren't even installed. Mail isn't installed. That's why I am logging to a file.

I could install these extra features, but then I'd be increasing the size of my docker container.

Comment: @thrig
Yes, I am aware. But shouldn't an error message be printed somewhere if this is the case? such as "Ignoring file due to insecure permissions?"

Comment: @user3460784 Did you ever figure this out and solve the problem? If so, can you post your own answer?

Comment: I suggest using [supercronic](https://github.com/aptible/supercronic) instead of _crond_.